# How to check duplicate CLOB - Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I have a table:

table1:

```
file_name    file_content
test.txt     Test content
test1.txt    Test content
```

file_content is CLOB.

I wrote a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(file_content),file_content FROM table1
  GROUP BY file_content HAVING COUNT(file_content) > 1;
```

It gives me error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
>
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 92 Column: 14

Is there a way to check for duplicate CLOBs?